# how to download file into aclient from server without Returning filepathresult

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

i saw this code for downloading a file into client from server...

```
 public ActionResult Download()
  {
     string file = @"c:\someFolder\foo.xlsx";
     string contentType = "application/pdf";   
    return File(file, controntType, Path.GetFileName(file));
  }
```

But the problem is that i have to do two different things in this Download method.Atfirst ,i want to download the file and then i need to get path of downloaded file and pass in to a documentviewr to display it.so i wrote this code in view razor.

```
 function navigate(target) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("Download", "Patient")',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        data: { 'filepath' : target },
        success: function (results) {
            event.preventDefault();
            documentViewr.loadDocument(results);
        },
        error: function () {
            alert('Error occured');
        }
    });
}
```

and in my controller i wrote this:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult Download(string filepath)
    {
        var content_type = "";
        //path = Path.Combine("D:\file1", filename);
        content_type = "application/pdf";
        FilePathResult file = File(filepath, content_type,  

         Path.GetFileName(filepath));
         String sDocID, sDocPath;
         ViewerController vc = new ViewerController();
        sDocPath = Server.MapPath(".") + "\\App_Data\\sample.docx";
        sDocID = vc.LoadDocument(sDocPath);

        return Json(sDocID, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

so my question is that how i can merge this two actions together?because if i do not return FilePathResult i can not download the file..my another question is that how i can define the path in which file will be downloded?can i tell it to download files into for example Server.MapPath(".") + "\App_Data\...??

i will be grateful if u can help me....

Comment: "can i tell it to download files into for example Server.MapPath(".") + "\App_Data\". No, because that's a path on the server. The files is downloading _from_ the server to the client. And you can't tell it where on the client to store the file because you don't know the structure of the client's disk, and anyway it would violate security restrictions on browsers - they don't have access to the filesystem in that way.

Comment: Also, does the current code not work, in some way?

Comment: Thank u for your reply...yess..I changed it a bit and it works now...actually I did not know that I can get the path of downloaded file from FilePathResult ..and I set the sDocPath to the path that I can get from FilePathResult and it works fine....

Comment: :(...at first I thought it works...but it does not work...How I can get the path of downloaded file...I mean after I download the file with this command FilePathResult file = File(filepath, content_type, 'xx.txt');
 how I can understand in which path file has stored?...I need to have this path..is there any way?